# Scaling/Interpolating measure data in C#

Tags: c#, interpolation, data-manipulation

First of all, I apologize if the question has already been asked, but in about 10 hours of intensive research on every single link Google offered for every single phrase I gave it, I wasn't able to find anything that could help me with my problem.

What I want to do is the following:

1. I retrieve two excel sheets with data from two different scientifical measurements. Each sheet contains information that can easily be compared to the other sheet, respectively.
   The only difference between the two sheets is the amount of data points they contain.
   *For example*: The first sheet contains data for a time span of 200 seconds, with one point representing 1 second. The second sheet also contains data for the same time span, **but** with one point representing 0.5 seconds.
2. The problem I have to solve, is to "scale" the sheet with less data points in a way that they can easily be compared in a single chart, so that each line in the chart uses the same space on the X axis.

The problem I'm having with this task is that im lacking sufficient mathematical background to create an algorithm.

I've already created the entire application with a GUI, the import of the excel sheets and smoothing with moving average (only useful if datasets have equal length).

Any idea or link to any place where this could be explained is welcome.

I also want to say that any code I currently have is completely irrelevant to this question, it's just about an additional method with said functionality.

Thanks in advance,
marfuc

Comment: This may not be the best place to get your answer. The question is more theoretical - "What are the different algorithms used for interpolation?". [so] is for more concrete problems. You could try [math.se].

Comment: @metacubed Thanks for the reply, I'll do that. Will it cause problems if I don't delete the question from here? Just in case someone browsing through knows something that could help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is a direct correlation between the data points of both sets - ie the time matches up for both - then it might be sufficient to do a linear interpolation on the smaller set to generate the missing points.

For instance, let's say your first set of data is:

```
Time        Value
12:00:00.0  100.0
12:00:01.0  120.0
12:00:02.0  117.5
```

...and your second set looks like:

```
Time        Value
12:00:00.0  2.5
12:00:00.5  3.0
12:00:01.0  2.6
12:00:01.5  2.9
12:00:02.0  2.8
```

We can fill in the gaps in the first list in a couple of ways, depending on what you're trying to do with the data afterwards.

The simplest is to do a linear interpolation of the values.  If your points are equidistant from the value you're looking for (ie: you're finding the value at the half-way point) then just average them together at the missing points:

```
Time        Value   Lerp
12:00:00.0  100.0
12:00:00.5          110.0
12:00:01.0  120.0
12:00:01.5          118.75
12:00:02.0  117.5
```

This is OK if the sample rate is high enough with relation to the rate at which the input varies.  I've seen a lot of audio processing algorithms that use this sort of calculation for doubling sample rate.  Doesn't work so well when you have high frequency data with sample rates that are too low to capture the transitions well.

The second option is to use a spline function to fit a curve against the series of points, then synthesize the missing points as offsets on the curve.  This will give you smoother and more natural interpolations, with humps in the data looking much more realistic.  This will also give you a fairly good way to offset your data if the timing isn't well aligned between the data sets - calculate each point as an offset along the curve with distance equal to the timing offset.  There are plenty of spline implementations out there that you could use for this.  I'd suggest Catmull-Rom as a starting algorithm.

**Warning:** If you're doing some sort of statistical analysis on the outputs then you're *not* going to get good results doing this, no matter how you do it.  Cut the bigger group down instead of fabricating data into the smaller group if analysis is your goal.